# Swfit - How can I use the UserDefaults to store variable and how to load the variable from UserDefaults next time

Tags: swiftyuserdefaults

I need to store some variables like ione and itwo which for method repeat.
The variables value will increase，after increased，I want to store the increased variables into userdefaults.

```
    import UIKit

    class ViewController: UIViewController 
{

    override func viewDidLoad() 
    {
    super.viewDidLoad()
/* How can I  load UserDefaults here to restore ione's value and 
           itwo's value and How to store them in UserDefaults ? */

let ionevalue = ione
println(ionevalue)

let itwovalue = itwo
println(itwovalue)

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
     }

 var ione = 0
 var itwo = 0
 ione++
 itwo++ 

 override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok，I finally got inspired in SOF and I figure it out，I initial a public NSUserDefaults can be used in any Func:

```
 let  aaa = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
```

and use below code to store the update value :

```
  aaa.setObject(AnythingYouInitialed, forKey: "DefineAKeyYouWant")
```

and use below code to load the value from NSUserDefaults:

```
 if let bbb = aaa.valueForKey("DefineAKeyYouWant") as?Int
    {
        ccc = bbb

    }
```

Now I have load the value and I can use it by assign ccc into other variabels.

I'm a old guy of 30 years old and I'm just starting be a programmer,that's not easy for me...haha...